# Dynamically get the parent element and process the dynamic child elements of xml in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried to iterate through the distinct child element of the parent node. to frame the expected xml
The below is my xml.

```
<NewDataSet>
<caseParticipants>
<Litigants>PORTFOLIO RECOVERY ASSOCIATES</Litigants>
<Attorneys>MANISCALCO, ANTHONY JOSEPH</Attorneys>
</caseParticipants>
<caseParticipants>
<Litigants>PLAINTIFF</Litigants>
<Attorneys>Plaintiff Attorney</Attorneys>
</caseParticipants>
<caseParticipants>
<Litigants />
<Attorneys />
<caseProceedings>
<Date>05/12/2015</Date>
<Details>PETITION/COMPLAINT NO DOC#</Details>
</caseProceedings>
<caseProceedings>
<Date>05/12/2015</Date>
<Details>ASM: SMALL CLAIMS $501-$2,500</Details>
</caseProceedings>
<caseCalendar>
<Date>06/30/2015 13:00:00</Date>
<Docket_x0020_Type>PRETRIAL CONF</Docket_x0020_Type>
<Judge>LANDT, ROBERT E</Judge>
<Location>XX : COURTR</Location>
</caseCalendar>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Assessment Total:</Column1>
<Column2>$185.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Assessment Paid:</Column1>
<Column2>$185.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Assessment Due:</Column1>
<Column2>$0.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Restitution Total:</Column1>
<Column2>$0.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Restitution Paid:</Column1>
<Column2>$0.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary>
<Column1>Restitution Due:</Column1>
<Column2>$0.00</Column2>
</caseFinancialSummary>
<caseFinancialSummary />
<caseFinancialdetails>
<Assessment_x0020_Due>$185.00</Assessment_x0020_Due>
<Assessment_x0020_Paid>$185.00</Assessment_x0020_Paid>
<Restitution_x0020_Due>$0.00</Restitution_x0020_Due>
<Restitution_x0020_Paid>$0.00</Restitution_x0020_Paid>
</caseFinancialdetails>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to transpose to xml like below.

```
<searchResult>
<caseDetails>
  <caseParticipants Label="Participants">
    <row>
      <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Litigants</colhead>
      <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Attorneys</colhead>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Portfolio Recovery Associates</cell>
      <cell id="2">Maniscalco, Anthony Joseph</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Plaintiff</cell>
      <cell id="2">Plaintiff Attorney</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1" />
      <cell id="2" />
    </row>
  </caseParticipants>
  <caseProceedings Label="Proceedings">
    <row>
      <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Date</colhead>
      <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Details</colhead>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">05/12/2015</cell>
      <cell id="2">Petition/Complaint no Doc#</cell>
      <document available="No" />
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">05/12/2015</cell>
      <cell id="2">Asm: Small Claims $501-$2,500</cell>
      <document available="No" />
    </row>
  </caseProceedings>
  <caseCalendar Label="Calendar">
    <row>
      <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Date</colhead>
      <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Docket Type</colhead>
      <colhead id="3" align="left" bold="no">Judge</colhead>
      <colhead id="4" align="left" bold="no">Location</colhead>
      <colhead id="5" align="left" bold="no">Prosecutor</colhead>
      <colhead id="6" align="left" bold="no">Defendant Attorney</colhead>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">06/30/2015 13:00:00</cell>
      <cell id="2">Pretrial Conf</cell>
      <cell id="3">Landt, Robert E</cell>
      <cell id="4">Xx : Courtr</cell>
      <cell id="5" />
      <cell id="6" />
    </row>
  </caseCalendar>
  <caseFinancialSummary Label="Financial Summary">
    <row>
      <colhead id="1" align="right" bold="no" />
      <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no" />
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Assessment Total:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Assessment Paid:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Assessment Due:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Restitution Total:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Restitution Paid:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">Restitution Due:</cell>
      <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
    </row>
  </caseFinancialSummary>
  <caseFinancialDetails Label="Financial Details">
    <row>
      <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Assessment Due</colhead>
      <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Assessment Paid</colhead>
      <colhead id="3" align="left" bold="no">Restitution Due</colhead>
      <colhead id="4" align="left" bold="no">Restitution Paid</colhead>
      <colhead id="5" align="left" bold="no">Payment Date</colhead>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">$185.00</cell>
      <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
      <cell id="3">$0.00</cell>
      <cell id="4">$0.00</cell>
      <cell id="5" />
    </row>
  </caseFinancialDetails>
</caseDetails>
```

I tried only one section like below for caseParticipant. i need to do like this for all nodes without giving the element name. since i get different type of elements of parent and child each time.

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="caseParticipants">
<xsl:variable name="vrtfEvalResult">
 <xsl:call-template name="eval">
   <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select="'/NewDataSet/caseParticipants'"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<row>
<cell id="1"><xsl:value-of select="Litigants" /></cell>
<cell id="2"><xsl:value-of select="Attorney" /></cell>
</row>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
 <xsl:template match="Path" name="eval">
<xsl:param name="pPath" select="."/>
<xsl:param name="pContext" select="/"/>
<xsl:choose>
<!-- If there is something to evaluate -->
<xsl:when test="string-length($pPath) >0">
  <xsl:variable name="vPath" select=
      "substring($pPath,2)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vNameTest">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($vPath, '/'))">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vPath"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select=
         "substring-before($vPath, '/')"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:call-template name="eval">
   <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select=
     "substring-after($pPath, $vNameTest)"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pContext" select=
    "$pContext/*[name()=$vNameTest]"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
 <!-- Otherwise we have evaluated completely the path -->
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:copy-of select="$pContext"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rethink this a bit to get it working, but I think this is what you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="distinct-second-level-elements" match="/*/*" use="local-name()" />
  <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <searchResults>
      <caseDetails>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[count(.|key('distinct-second-level-elements', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:variable name="currNodeName" select="local-name()" />
          <xsl:element name="{$currNodeName}">
            <xsl:attribute name="Label">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($currNodeName, 'case')" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <row>
              <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <colhead id="{position()}" align="left" bold="no">
                  <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)" />
                </colhead>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name() = $currNodeName]">
              <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                  <cell id="{position()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </caseDetails>
    </searchResults>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. Use a key to get your distinct second level node names, and iterate through that key a la [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) - which is apparently all I write about in the XSLT tag these days ;)
2. Nest some more `for-each`es in there to grab the children of other nodes with the same name and layout your rows/cells

All of this is done using things like `local-name()` and selectors that go by depth (e.g. `/*/*`), so it should work regardless of the node names **as long as your structure stays consistent**.

One note - [`id` attributes should be unique in a document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/#intro), so this is technically not valid XML - but I'm assuming that it's just a requirement of a downstream consumer who isn't following the standard quite right.  If that's not the case, you should probably pick a different name for that attribute if possible.

Output:

```
<searchResults>
  <caseDetails>
    <caseParticipants Label="Participants">
      <row>
        <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Litigants</colhead>
        <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Attorneys</colhead>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">PORTFOLIO RECOVERY ASSOCIATES</cell>
        <cell id="2">MANISCALCO, ANTHONY JOSEPH</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">PLAINTIFF</cell>
        <cell id="2">Plaintiff Attorney</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1"></cell>
        <cell id="2"></cell>
      </row>
    </caseParticipants>
    <caseProceedings Label="Proceedings">
      <row>
        <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Date</colhead>
        <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Details</colhead>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">05/12/2015</cell>
        <cell id="2">PETITION/COMPLAINT NO DOC#</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">05/12/2015</cell>
        <cell id="2">ASM: SMALL CLAIMS $501-$2,500</cell>
      </row>
    </caseProceedings>
    <caseCalendar Label="Calendar">
      <row>
        <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Date</colhead>
        <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Docket_x0020_Type</colhead>
        <colhead id="3" align="left" bold="no">Judge</colhead>
        <colhead id="4" align="left" bold="no">Location</colhead>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">06/30/2015 13:00:00</cell>
        <cell id="2">PRETRIAL CONF</cell>
        <cell id="3">LANDT, ROBERT E</cell>
        <cell id="4">XX : COURTR</cell>
      </row>
    </caseCalendar>
    <caseFinancialSummary Label="FinancialSummary">
      <row>
        <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Column1</colhead>
        <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Column2</colhead>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Assessment Total:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Assessment Paid:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Assessment Due:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Restitution Total:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Restitution Paid:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">Restitution Due:</cell>
        <cell id="2">$0.00</cell>
      </row>
      <row />
    </caseFinancialSummary>
    <caseFinancialdetails Label="Financialdetails">
      <row>
        <colhead id="1" align="left" bold="no">Assessment_x0020_Due</colhead>
        <colhead id="2" align="left" bold="no">Assessment_x0020_Paid</colhead>
        <colhead id="3" align="left" bold="no">Restitution_x0020_Due</colhead>
        <colhead id="4" align="left" bold="no">Restitution_x0020_Paid</colhead>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell id="1">$185.00</cell>
        <cell id="2">$185.00</cell>
        <cell id="3">$0.00</cell>
        <cell id="4">$0.00</cell>
      </row>
    </caseFinancialdetails>
  </caseDetails>
</searchResults>
```

Comment: No problem - my rule of thumb is that whenever I want a "distinct" or "group" in XSLT, try to think about how to use a `key` to get there